# How is the name of the first item in the MacOS app menu localized?

Tags: swift, macos, menu

I found that the name of the first menu was dictated by BundleName and $(PRODUCT_NAME). I wanted him to support localization, and each region displayed a name, but I didn't find it.

Are there any relevant documents or cases that can give me some help, thank you?.

Comment: "the name of the first menu was dictated by BundleName and $(PRODUCT_NAME)."  Nope.  That's not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project, add a `Strings` file named `InfoPlist.strings` and add an entry for `CFBundleName` then localize the file and the entry per supported language:

```
CFBundleName = "¡Mi aplicación!";
```

This will allow the name of the app to appear localized in the app menu and also in the standard about panel.

Other `Info.plist` string entries can be localized in the `InfoPlist.strings` file as well (e.g., `CFBundleGetInfoString`, `NSHumanReadableCopyright`, `NSContactsUsageDescription`, etc.). To see the keys in Xcode, open the Info.plist file and control-click in the editor pane of the plist to see the contextual menu and select `Show Raw Keys/Values`.